# Kendo ui upload widget

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, kendo-ui

I was trying to understand the Kendo UI Upload widget from the Kendo documentation. Most of the events fires only in async mode which means i should be having a handler to read the uploaded file and save. However, i have a large html form where users will enter all the required fields and then upload the supported documents and finally Submit the form. At this point i want to save all the details along with the attachments and not when user uploads the file. I mean avoid saving the files during the upload instead save only when the html form is submitted.  Let me know how can i achieve this with Kendo UI.

Thanks,
Mallikarjun

Comment: You can do this by setting the async autoUpload: false -

Answer (score 0):

simply define a kendouploader no need special handling

```
$("#files").kendoUpload();
```

when you submit the form check

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["files"]; // one (if you need more take a list)
```

**solution not tested**

Comment: My form is a html form and not an aspx page. On "Submitting" the html page, i will be using the JQuery ajax to call the WCF service to update the details. I don't think "Request" object will be accessible. It will be null. Anyways let me try this to confirm.

Comment: if it is a ajax call it will not work , you will have to handle it separately

Comment: basically have  a handler to read the uploaded file and keep the data in a Temp session, and on submit take the data and clear those  temp data

Comment: Any sample of the handler will be appreciated.